# find entry with needed information

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to come up with a sql query related to division,
I have relational schemas like these:

```
property(PNO, price, fid); //PNO is the primary key, fid is the feature id, price is the price of the house
buyer(PEID, max_price, fid);//PEID is the primary key, fid is the feature id, max_price is the max price a buyer can pay for a house
feature(FID, content);
```

One property can have many features. One buyer can require multiple features.

The relationship I want to build is this :  for each buyer, list all the properties that meet buyer's requirements (features and price).
I tried many different ways, but still can not come up with the desired output.

Sample data would be like

```
//buyers require 0 - many features, and price is the maximum price they can pay for a house, not for a single feature
buyer(0, 10k, 1)
buyer(0, 10k, 2)       //buyer 0 can pay 10k, and requires feature 1 and 2
buyer(1, 15k, 3)
buyer(1, 15k, 4)       //buyer 1 can pay 15k, and requires feature 3 and 4
buyer(2, 150k, null)   //buyer 2 can pay 150k, and no specific requirement
buyer(3, 20k, null)    //buyer 3 can pay 20k, and no specific requirement

//property has 0 - many features, and price is the selling price of the house, not for a single feature
property(5, 5k, 1)
property(5, 5k, 2)     //property 5 is 5k, and has feature 1 and 2
property(6, 6k, 1)
property(6, 6k, 4)     //property 6 is 6k, and has feature 1 and 4
property(7, 6k, 1)
property(7, 6k, 2)
property(7, 6k, 3)
property(7, 6k, 4)     //property 7 is 6k, and has feature 1,2,3,4
property(8, 100k, 3)
property(8, 100k, 4)   //property 8 is 100k, and has feature 3,4

feature(1, '2000 square feet')
feature(2, 'two story')
feature(2, 'one story')
feature(4, 'two bathrooms')
```

Sample output would be like

```
buyer     property
-----      --------
0             5        //buyer 0 can afford property 5 with required features
0             7        //buyer 0 can afford property 7 with required features
1             7        //buyer 1 can afford property 7 with required features
2             5        //buyer 2 can afford property 5 
2             6        //buyer 2 can afford property 6 
2             7        //buyer 2 can afford property 7 
2             8        //buyer 2 can afford property 8 
3             5        //buyer 3 can afford property 5 
3             6        //buyer 3 can afford property 6
3             7        //buyer 3 can afford property 7
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What does division have to so with this? Please provide attempted query.

Comment: Hey I modified my question, and it does need a division, I tried to use correlated subquery, but it doesn't work.

Comment: It's not clear what the `features` are? Is it a table only? If so what are the columns? Where are the sample data for each table, and waht's the expected result from the query at last?

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan, I modified the question, please take a look.

Comment: You should normalize your data model. As is, there can be different money amounts for a buyer. Same for a property. These ambiguities should not be allowed in a proper database. Or is just your explanation wrong and buyer 1 is ready to pay 10k for feature 1 plus 10k for feature 2 and the features for property 5 cost 5k each?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner, one buyer can have multiple required features. for example, buyer 0 can pay 10k at most for a house, and this buyer requires feature 1 and feature 2 in this house.             
buyer(PEID, max_price, fid); // in this table, fid is a single value attribute, so if a buyer wants more than one feature, there will be multiple tuples for this buyer with different feature ids, the max_price for each buyer stays the same. and same for the property table. Thanks.

Comment: I am just saying that this is not how to build a database. Your database allows two rows `buyer(0, 10k, 1)` and `buyer(0, 100k, 2)`. How much is the buyer ready to pay in this case? 10k? 100k? 110k? Your database lacks two tables: a `buyer` table with one row per buyer (you only have a `buyer_feature` table you mistakenly call `buyer`) and a `property` table with one row per property (again your database only has a `property_feature` table you mistakenly call `property`).

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner, it's buyer(0, 10k, 1) and buyer(0, 10k, 2), the tables I am showing are already after some manipulation to show only the needed information. Original tables would be too many information...

Comment: Ah, okay, we are looking at query results here, then. No problem then. I'll think of an answer...

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner, and I think this problem will need a division, even though I list all the original tables, you will eventually come up with this aggregated buyer table and this aggregated property table as divisor and dividend, I just don't know how to do a division between tables in sql.

Comment: Yes, in relational algebra this is called division. However, relational algebra is something that only few people working with databases are actually familiar with. And it is something that SQL doesn't support directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that what you are showing is not the real tables, but query results on underlying tables. This is good for otherwise your database would not be normalized and thus prone to errors.

I assume in the followwing answer a properly normalized database:

- feature (feature_id, description)
- buyer (buyer_id, money, ...)
- buyer_feature (buyer_id, feature_id)
- property (property_id, money, ...)
- property_feature (property_id, feature_id)

We select from buyers and properties where the price matches. Then we see whether we find a missing feature for the found buyer/property pair.

```
select
  b.buyer_id, p.property_id,
  case when exists
    (
      select feature_id from buyer_feature bf where bf.buyer_id = b.buyer_id
      minus
      select feature_id from property_feature pf where pf.property_id = p.property_id
    )
    then 'feature(s) missing'
    else 'all feature requirements met'
  end as feature_status
from buyer b
join property p on p.money <= b.money
order by b.buyer_id, p.property_id;
```

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot! Yeah, division is not supported in sql, and this is causing such a headache for me...

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `join`:

```
select b.*, p.*
from buyer b left join
     property p
     on p.price <= b.max_price;
```

If you want this all on one row, you can use aggregation:

```
select b.PEID, b.max_price,
       listagg(pno, ',') within group (order by pno) as pnos
from buyer b left join
     property p
     on p.price <= b.max_price
group by PEID, max_price
```

Comment: Hi, I was missing something in the original post and I modified the question. It will need a division and the left join would only solve part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need aggregation through grouping by `peid` and `price` columns while joining subqueries having `buyer` and `property` tables with join conditions composed of concatenations of properties such as

```
SELECT b.peid AS buyer, p.pno AS property
  FROM ( SELECT LISTAGG(fid,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY fid) AS features, pno 
           FROM property
          GROUP BY pno ) p
  JOIN ( SELECT LISTAGG(fid,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY fid) AS features, peid 
           FROM buyer
          GROUP BY peid ) b
    ON b.features = p.features;

 BUYER  PROPERTY 
 0      5     
 1      6
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e5a1b700d66f909efcee656c9a5d9bc5)</kbd>

Comment: thanks for replying, but the query would display the buyer with required features, what I need is a table of buyer and satisfied property. and also, in my example, only property 5 satisfies buyer 0's need and only property 6 satisfies buyer 1's need.

Comment: The query would take care of the needed features part, and how can I take price into consideration too? A buyer can only afford a house less than his/her max_price. Thanks.

Comment: please share what output exactly you want to see by editing the queston @Ashley

Comment: Hi, I modified the question, and hope this version is clearer, thanks.